# Solve $\lim_{x \to 1} x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$ using Taylor's expansion

Tags: limits, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have to solve the following limit using Taylor's series:

$$
\lim_{x \to 1} x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}
$$

I can perfectly solve this limit using normal limit properties - such as L'Hospital and chain rules -, but I'm struggling to solve it using Taylor's expansion. I tried the following:

I start with a basic $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$.

Then, I rearrange the original limit and substitute the above result in it:

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 1} x^{\frac{1}{1-x}} &= \lim_{x \to 1} e^{\ln{x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}}}\\
 &= \lim_{x \to 1} e^{\frac{1}{1-x}\ln{x}}\\
 &= \lim_{x \to 1} e^{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n \ln{x}}\\
 &= \lim_{x \to 1} e^{(1 + x + x^2 + ...) \ln{x}}\\
\end{align*}
$$

And then I struggle. In order to this limit result in $\frac{1}{e}$, the exponent $(1 + x + x^2 + ...)\cdot\ln{x}$ must equal -1. However I'm unable to understand how can this be possible, since, to me, it should approach 0 as $x$ approaches 1.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: If you are using Taylor's expansion, try the Taylor expansion of $\ln x$ at the point $x=1$.  Expanding $\frac{1}{1-x}$ at $0$ is no help for the limit at $1$.  For the limit at $1$ you need the Taylor expansion at $1$.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Math! My suggestion would be try rewriting ln(x) as a power series and working from there. Hint: $ln(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(x-1)^n}{n}$.

Comment: Put $x=1+y$ so that $y\to 0$ as $x\to 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your solution:

(1). For $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k$ to be held, $x$ must satisfy $|x|<1$.

(2). When you handle $\lim_{x\to1}(1 + x + x^2 + ...) \ln{x}$, you use $\infty \cdot 0=0$, it is not true.

Therefore you can't use (1). What you have to do is to use the Taylor series of $\ln x=\ln(1+(x-1))$ at $x=1$ and then you will get the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I've got so obsessed with the familiar $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^k$ that I forgot the preconditions regarding $\mid x \mid$.

Restarting the solution using the expansion of $ln x$ did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

You're making things more complex than they really are. By the substitution $x=1+h\;(h\to 0)$, you only need an expansion at order $1$, i.e.  a standard high school limit. Indeed
$$ x^{\tfrac{1}{1-x}}=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\ln x}{1-x}}=\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{\ln (1+h)}{h}}$$
Now , it is well-known from high school that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\ln (1+h)}{h}=1$, whence the sought limit $\mathrm e^{-1}$.

Comment: I agree that this basic approach would be so much easier, but the assignment requires me to use a Taylor's expansion when solving the limit.

Comment: Well, at order $1$, you have $\ln(1+h)=h+o(h)$, whence instantly,  $\frac{\ln(1+h)}h=\frac{h+o(h)}h=1+o(1)$, and the trick is done.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take it from your last line. We have $$L=\lim _{x\rightarrow 1}\exp\left(\sum ^{\infty }_{k=0} x^{k} \cdot \ln( x)\right)$$
Then using a first order Taylor expansion of $\ln$ about $x=1$, $$L \approx \lim _{x\rightarrow 1}\exp\left(\sum ^{\infty }_{k=0} x^{k} \cdot ( 1-x)\right)$$
$$=\lim _{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{\exp\left(\sum ^{\infty }_{k=0} x^{k}\right)}{\exp\left(\sum ^{\infty }_{k=0} x^{k+1}\right)}$$
$$=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\lim _{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{\prod ^{n}_{k=0}\exp\left( x^{k}\right)}{\prod ^{n}_{k=0}\exp\left( x^{k+1}\right)}$$
$$=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\lim _{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{1}{\exp\left( x^{n+1}\right)}$$
$$=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{e} =\frac{1}{e}.$$

Comment: This assumes we take a limit from the *left* hand side (i.e, from values of $x$ less than $1$.)  More care must be taken to evaluate from the right hand side.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I can't ignore the limit approaching 1 by the right side and this seems to be one of the errors I was making. But thanks for your answer anyways.